# Does Vegan Certification Have Any Halachic Weight?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, trust-neemanut

There are a number of organizations that offer Vegan Certification for food products; the concept is the same as kosher certification, (though that is the only similarity). Examples would be [Vegan.org](http://vegan.org/certify/) or [vegansociety.org](http://www.vegansociety.com/pdf/TrademarkProducts.pdf)

Do these certifications, in general, or any of them in particular, have any Halachic weight? Can they be trusted to certify, for example, that a processed product is neither dairy nor meaty, or that its ingredients contain no non-kosher animal products, or that a vegetable product contains no insects?

Comment: What makes you think these certifications have halakhic significance (that presumably ingredient labels don't have?)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I don't.

Comment: So..... nu?  Why ask?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Conversation in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10667585#10667585

Comment: Why would these be any worse than government inspections of milk? (Everyone believes them; it's just a question if that solves the formal halachik problem of the gezera of chalav akum.)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Why don't ingredients have halachik significance? You think they are lying?

Comment: Well then, who says the levels of supervision are comparable to the government? Even if they are, who says that that's good enough? Even by milk it's not universally agreed upon, so what about other issurim, where it's far more likely/easier/cheaper to get away with?

Comment: @HodofHod Who doesn't trust the government supervision of milk??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10003/discussion-between-hodofhod-and-double-aa)

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't say that ingredients had no halakhic significance.  This question seems to posit that vegan certification is something beyond an ingredients list.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30376/if-the-label-says-o-u-d-but-the-warning-label-for-allery-sufferers-says-no-dai

Comment: I recall a Rav saying vegan certification on shoe blacking would suffice for its use for _tefillin_.

Comment: two problems:  1) they don't have ne'emanut.  2) bugs.  You would be amazed at how many "vegans" actually have no problem eating bugs.  Some of them do it on purpose, declaring that they aren't really "animals".....

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36442/759

Answer (score 7):

Here's a [list](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/547235/jewish/Are-vegan-restaurants-kosher.htm) of potential issues (one specifically mentioning the Vegan Society and its standards) with vegan-certified food:

1. The vegan standards for "animal-free" may be less stringent than the halakhic standards. I've heard this is particularly true with respect to bug checking for vegetables.
2. Keilim. In particular, even if the restaurant's own keilim are fine, they are not necessarily committed to buying hechshered products (e.g., canned beans). So there could very well be an issue higher up in the supply chain.
3. Wine and grape juice
4. Bishul akum

Here's an old [thread](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v44/index.html#VKB) on mail.jewish about whether it's allowed to eat in a Jain restaurant, since Jains are extremely "machmir" about animal products.

Comment: Regarding keilim, bishul akum and yayin Stam, it's not a problem in cold salad

Comment: @DavidFeigen Maris Ayin could also be a problem.