# Eating dairy after pareve on meat equipment?

Tags: halacha, time, meat-and-milk

If I eat hot pareve food that was made on meat equipment, is there a waiting period before I can eat dairy?  I had always assumed so -- that the heat transfers the meatiness to the pareve food -- but the [Oreo question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30376/472), which in a sense is the inverse of this question, makes me wonder.  But it's possible the considerations are different for meat and dairy, or that there is something about how Oreos are made that's different from, say, my pot of vegetarian chili.

So if I've got this vegetarian chili made in a meat pot, can I have ice cream for dessert?  (This isn't a p'sak question, even if I get an answer before lunch.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43582/759

Comment: similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49181

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the Star-K:](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-kosher-cons-handbk.htm)

> If one ate pareve food that was cooked in a fleishig  pot, one is not required to wait six hours before eating dairy. However, one may not eat this food together with dairy or reheat it in a dairy pot. For example, if one cooked spaghetti in a fleishig pot he may eat cheese immediately after finishing the spaghetti. However, he may not eat the spaghetti with cheese or with other dairy products. He should also not reheat the spaghetti in a milchig pot. One who ate meat may eat pareve food that was cooked in a clean milchig pot after finishing the meat. Products that are certified Kosher and do not contain dairy, but have been heated or processed on dairy equipment (e.g. the Kashrus agency informed the consumer or the label states “DE” next to the symbol), may be eaten immediately after meat – but not together with meat.

I have heard from a Rabbi that in the case of leftovers, there is additional room for leniency as this is considered an "after the fact" (בדיעבד) situation, but I suggest you consult yours on that question.

Comment: "He should also not reheat the spaghetti in a milchig pot." Hmmm. I wonder why? [The Rama](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%94#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91) is clear that you can put Nat bar Nat from a Ben Yomo on opposite gendered dishes. I accept that if the milchig pot is ben yomo then you end up with noodles into which you can't mix meat or milk but that doesn't seem like a basis for prohibition.

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50638

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to wait between eating the food cooked in a meat pot and dairy.
There is a difference of opinions regarding eating food that was cooked in a meat pot together with dairy. Askenazim hold that you shouldn't mix the "bechazkat" food with the other, and Sephardim hold that once it was cooked you may then eat them together. (answer was based on a post ) [pocketrabbi.com's facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/PocketRabbi)