# Permissible to consume something from milk dishes while still fleishig

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

Is it permissible to consume something hot from milk dishes if one is still fleishig from a meat meal?

Comment: It would greatly improve the question if you would [edit] in the motivation and why you think it might be.

Comment: opposite http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34562/759

Comment: You mean something parve that's on milk dishes, I assume?

Comment: @MonicaCellio the checkmark (below) would seem to imply as much. (The other way to read this question would be with "dishes" meaning "quiche and the like", but I didn't think of that before answering.)

Comment: It may be even permissible to eat the pareve food which was cooked in a pot which was not used 24 hours with a milky food together with meat http://www.kosharot.co.il/ask_print.asp?id=13244
For ashkenazim it is not allowed to plan itbut for sfaradim it is allowed to plan it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> One who ate meat may eat *pareve* food [=neither meat nor dairy] that was cooked in a clean *milchig* [=dairy] pot after finishing the meat.

― [the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/706/), citing [Rabbi *Aharon* Kotler](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Kotler)