After eating parve food cooked in a meat pot, and before eating dairy — must you bentsch?
First, you ate some bread. Next, you ate some pareve chili which was cooked in a meat pot. You haven't said the Blessing after Meals yet.
Now you'd like to eat some dairy food.
A.)  Must you say Grace after Meals immediately before eating the dairy food, in order to try to make the dairy food become a "separate meal"?
B.)  If bentsching before eating the dairy food is unnecessary:  Why is it unnecessary?

Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34562/eating-dairy-after-pareve-on-meat-equipment

@DoubleAA That's not quite answering the same question. The requirement to bentch between milk and meat is separate from the waiting period.

@shmosel If there was a requirement to bentch in the case of meat equiptment vegetarian chili followed by dairy dessert, a complete answer there will surely say so. So it is a duplicate per meta https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3509/759

Is the pot a Ben yomo? Has the pot been thoroughly cleaned before use? If there was still meat residue in the pot itself then it doesn't matter if it was parve..

@Awtsmoos no even then it's ok, see Shach YD 89:19

@DoubleAA see https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Waiting_between_Meat_and_Milk&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#cite_note-34 If one cooked parve in a dirty meat pot whether one needs to wait 6 hours after eating that food is a dispute.[33] Others are strict.[34]  [33] Shach 89:19 is lenient. Yad Yehuda 89:5 explains that he is lenient even if the pot was dirty and not nullified in 60. [34] Eliya Rabba 173:4 argues on the Shach completely. Badei Hashulchan 89:89 seems to be strict as he quotes Eliya Rabba at the end.

In the case of parve food cooked in a clean meat pot, there is no need to wait before eating dairy and no need to say birkat hamazon. Indeed should the parve food become mixed together with milk, you could even eat them together after the fact.
R Yitzchak Yaakov Fuchs describes it in his book Hakashrut (p. 373)

One may eat dairy foods immediately after eating parve food that was
cooked in a meaty pot even if the pot was not thoroughly cleansed from
the greasiness of the meat that was cooked earlier in it.

(YD 89:3 with Schach 19. See also here for a summary, and here for the detailed laws. Please note that this doesn't mean you can mix the chili together with dairy.)
Saying birkat hamazon might in fact create a problematic situation of unnecessary blessings. This is because you knew before saying birkat hamazon that you still wanted to eat more.
In this area, small details can make a big difference. So, consult your rabbi
before implementing anything you learn here.
