# Allergen information says "may contain..."

Tags: hechsher-certification, dairy

If a product is labeled dairy, but the allergen information says "may contain traces of milk," can I assume that it is actually only dairy equipment?  If it didn't say anything, maybe they just didn't list it, which I have heard is done.  But if it does list it, but says "may contain," is that reliable?

Comment: I have seen the "may contain traces" on things that actually contain on the ingredient panel. In any event, the correct way to proceed is to call the certification and see what they say.

Comment: My specific example was a bag of dark chocolate chips.  I asked my Rov and he said better not to rely on it.  But he didn't sound sure, and I was curious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If the label says O-U D, but the warning label for allery sufferers says "no dairy", do we consider the product dairy or not?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30376/if-the-label-says-o-u-d-but-the-warning-label-for-allery-sufferers-says-no-dai)

Comment: @IsaacMoses "may contain traces" could be different from "does not contain any"?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I guess so.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Hi! I was wondering about when it says "may contain" because then maybe I could assume that they aren't just omitting it.  Which I think seems like what I am reading in those answers over there, that it may be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You should check with the authority who gives the Hechsher (Kashrut certification). Sometimes the OU will put OU(D) on products that are merely made on dairy equipment but are not actually dairy, but there may be a very good reason as to why they put OU(D).

Comment: Shalom Big Joe and welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Prior to about 2 years ago, OU had a designation OU DE, meaning "Dairy equipment". I asked someone in charge of OU kashrut what that meant and he explained that you could eat the product with meat but not on the same plate. Because the DE seignation confused most consumers, myself included, OU dropped the E and marks everything as "dairy" even if it is DE. They do this for safety, but, now for those who want to eat such products, the "reality is hidden" unless you contact someone from the OU directly, or you otherwise are familiar with the product (e.g. - you asked and u regularly use it.)

Answer (score 0):

[London Beth Din Nosh 2014 guide](http://noshguide.theus.org.uk/#p=2) says

> Due to a change in labelling regulations, there is generally an
>   allergen warning  on products which, although not containing Dairy
>   ingredients, are processed in  close proximity to or in the same
>   factory as, products containing Dairy ingredients.  Such products may
>   still have the halachic status of Parev, even when bearing the 
>   warning ‘contains traces of milk’. The KLBD always takes into account
>   shared use of  production equipment and cleandown procedures when
>   determining the kosher  status of a product.

Some Green & Black’s Organic chocolate is listed by the Guide as P = parev. See below

> P Dark Chocolate 70%
>
> P Dark Chocolate 85%

[Green & Black's themselves say in their FAQs](http://www.greenandblacks.co.uk/frequently-asked-questions)

> What has changed with your milk allergen labelling?
>
> WHY HAS THE ALLERGEN WARNING CHANGED?
>
> The new communication will highlight milk as
>   an ingredient in its previously labelled ‘vegan’ dark organic
>   chocolate bars. As both the milk chocolate and dark chocolate bars are
>   made using the same production line there is a risk of cross contact.
>   A recent audit revealed that traces of milk residues can still be
>   found on manufacturing equipment despite intensive cleaning.

So it is possible to find parev products labelled as containing milk.

London Beth Din seem to take the position that products not containing Dairy ingredients, processed on the same intensively cleaned equipment as products containing Dairy ingredients can still have the halachic status of Parev.

If a product is labelled dairy, certainly according to LBD, there is real reason to think it contains important quantities of milk. As Big Joe says "check with the authority who gives the Hechsher".