# Creating a crowd-sourced database of non-dairy OU-D products

Tags: kashrut-kosher, internet, hechsher-certification, dairy, keilim

Several questions/answers on this site have pointed out that the OU-D hechsher does not always mean that the product is actually dairy. (But that it is, in reality, "OU-DE" [dairy equipment]. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30376/if-the-label-says-o-u-d-but-the-warning-label-for-allery-sufferers-says-no-dai) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44517/allergen-information-says-may-contain?lq=1), for example.)

According to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44519/4794) answer, the only real recourse is to call the certifying agency and ask them.

I would like to create a list of products which people have contacted the OU about and been told that they are indeed pareve.  Please try to maintain the alphabetical order of the list, and list the approximate date of your obtaining this information.

Related: [Can I trust a random internet user?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48034/4794)

Comment: Interesting question; +1. But why is it tagged [tag:internet]? It has to do with the Internet precisely what every other question on MY does: that it's *on* the Internet.

Comment: thanks for reminding me to send my every-three-months super annoying e-mail to the OU...

Comment: It can change without warning

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The OU has told me in my quarterly email that I can rely on the chazaka for three months (which is why I bother them every three months with a list of 30 products, and why I think that the lack of DE is much more of a michshol than a seyag; people will always just assume that Oreos for example aren't really dairy even if one day that changes)

Comment: Does the person who downvoted want to explain their opposition to this list?

Comment: Would it make sense to also list products that you asked about that were confirmed dairy?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I dunno - I assume if something isn't confirmed as pareve you need to treat it as dairy, so confirmed dairy is as good as unconfirmed for most purposes.

Comment: YeZ, @IsaacMoses, confirmed dairy products can be used to fulfill the _minhag_ of eating dairy dishes on _Chanuka_ or _Shavuos_.

Comment: @Matt care to add your list to this list, for public benefit?

Comment: YeZ, happy to. I also have a similar list of "confirmed" dairy (product that the manufacturers claim will not harm someone who's allergic to dairy but apparently are still halakhically dairy) cc: @IsaacMoses

Comment: You might further improve your question by including contact details for some of the major Kashrut orgs.

Comment: `if something isn't confirmed as pareve you need to treat it as dairy` It should be noted that many applications of milk status would regard rabinnic laws or mere customs. It seems reasonable that in these cases safek d'rabana l'kula would apply. (although one can quibble...) @Yez

Comment: If there is a specific product that you are interested in, you can call OU to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer has been marked "community wiki," which means that it's open to all<sup>1</sup> to [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/48038/edit). Please do!  Please preserve the alphabetical order of the list.  If you do not see something on the list, consider that it may be alphabetized by the product name or the brand name.

Note: The [Product Search](https://oukosher.org/product-search/) feature on the OU Kosher website [now indicates](https://oukosher.org/blog/news/ou-kosher-adds-two-new-options-to-consumer-product-search-website/) DE status for SOME OU D products.

Please include the date at which you obtained your information.  Outdated information (reportedly more than 3 months old) may not be reliable.

- Aunt Jemima Pancake Syrup (March 12, 2015 or so.)
- Betty Crocker Frostings - anything that doesn't say "contains dairy" in the allergen warning - Dec 25, 2014
- Blue Diamond Almond Breeze Almond Milk - all varieties - December 2014
- Chex Mix Traditional - October 2016
- Cap'n Crunch Cereal - Original - Dec 25, 2014
- Cinammon Toast Cruch - October 2016
- Cracker Jack (popcorn snacks) - Dec 25, 2014
- Gardetto's snacks - Dec 25, 2014
- General Mills Honey Nut Clusters - October 2016
- Golden Grahams cereal - Dec 25, 2014
- Haagen Dazs Sorbets - Dec 25, 2014
- Hershey's Simply 5 syrup - Sep 12, 2023
- Kellogg's Graham Cracker Crumbs - September 8, 2023
- Luden's Sore Throat Lozenges - January 2015
- Nabisco Graham Crackers and Teddy Grahams - Dec 25, 2014
- Nesquik - original chocolate-flavored powder (all Nequick powder is not dairy EXCEPT the no sugar added, which is actually dairy[DE Status of Strawberry verified via email 3/20/2024]) - Dec 25, 2014
- New York Style Bagel Crisps EXCEPT cheese flavored - October 2016
- Oreo - February 2020<sup>2, 3</sup>:

  - Original Oreo Sandwich Cookies
  - Oreo Double Stuf Sandwich Cookies
  - Oreo Original Mega Stuff Sandwich Cookie
  - Mini Original Oreo Sandwich Cookies
  - Chocolate Oreo Sandwich Cookies
  - Golden Oreo Sandwich Cookies
  - Triple Double Oreo Sandwich Cookies
  - Oreo Thins Sandwich Cookies
  - (See the [OU website](https://oukosher.org/faqs/what-is-the-status-of-oreo-sandwich-cookies-do-they-contain-actual-dairy-ingredients-2/) for 10+ more)
- Pringles, if the ingredients don’t state ‘whey’ or ‘milk’ - April 24, 2018<sup>4</sup>
- Quaker Oatmeal Squares Cereal - Dec 25, 2014
- Snyder's Pretzels - Unflavored - Dec 25, 2014
- Stop and Shop Orange Juice - Dec 25, 2014
- Trader Joe's Everything But the Bagel Seasoned Bite Sized Crackers - Aug 11, 2022
- Trader Joe's Organic Garlic Naan Crackers - Aug 11, 2022

---

<sup>1) "All" = reputation > 99, but it's close enough.</sup>

<sup>2) R' Akiva Dovid Weiss reported in a [public Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/rakiva.weiss/posts/10157720387950370) in October 2016: "Just got off phone with OU: Official OU Policy concerning Oreos and whether they are Dairy: ALL regular Oreos (black cookie, white creme), REGARDLESS of thickness (with the exception of the Reduced Fat ones), are DAIRY EQUIPMENT ONLY; not Dairy. ANY colored or other kind of Oreos (including Reduced Fat Oreos) are actually DAIRY."</sup>

<sup>3) Current list per [OU web page](https://oukosher.org/faqs/what-is-the-status-of-oreo-sandwich-cookies-do-they-contain-actual-dairy-ingredients-2/) in February 2020.</sup>

<sup>4) [OU web page](https://oukosher.org/kosher-alerts/kosher-advisory-pringles/), April 2018</sup>

Comment: @Matt (or anyone), do you have more recent info than what's here? Would you mind updating?

Comment: Should older listings be erased?