# Are Belvita Breakfast Biscuits dairy or just dairy equipment?

Tags: halacha, dairy

Are Belvita Breakfast Biscuits dairy or just made on dairy equipment?

The Hechsher says OU'D but it doesn't seem to have any dairy ingredients in it. The allergy information only says contains soy and wheat. One of the ingredients is "Natural Flavoring", which can be the dairy. But I think it's not, since there is no allergic warning for dairy. It's also produced by Nabisco, the maker of Oreos. Which Oreos too say (OU'D) but some of them are really not dairy. They're just dairy equipment.

Comment: Email the OU and let us know. That's all anyone here will do. None of us work at Nabisco to know in any other way.

Comment: And post your answer [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48037/creating-a-crowd-sourced-database-of-non-dairy-ou-d-products)

Comment: (And only some oreo's are dairy equipment. Some are actually dairy. You should call the OU about each flavor.)

Comment: Only added request, if you have not yet called is to ask them if they have a general rule that if any product that they mark OU-D but does not list "obvious" diary ingredient can be assumed to be dairy equipment. I doubt that, but, who knows? If not, perhaps, they have released some publication of brands that are actually dairy equipment. I know that about 2 years ago, they changed their policy and have stopped using the "DE" label. Personally, I think it's an unnecessary *chumra*, but, that was their decision.

Comment: There actually dairy. Next time, just call the OU 212-613-8241

Comment: I think OP should specify if the question is about the OU's opinion or the clean-cut halachah.

Answer (score 1):

Just called OU and they said the dairy is in the flavoring.

Comment: Rose, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for doing the legwork and sharing this result! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.