# May a person order food from a vegan restaurant

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, vegetables, restaurant

May a person order food from a vegan restaurant? — assuming you aren't ordering cooked food, to avoid the problem of bishul akum. If your ordering let's say a salad, what could be the problem? There's no problem of bliya (absorption) with the utensils because they only serve vegan food which doesn't contain meat, fish, or milk. And it's raw so it's not bishul akum. Assume it's the diaspora, too.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you order kosher food it's kosher food. If you order non-kosher food it's non-kosher food.

Comment: With salads, one serious problem is the likelihood of bugs.

Comment: What about _b'lios_ from _bishul-akum_ food?

Comment: Msh210 read my question again carefully. I said that there is no problem of bliya because they don't use anything that would cause the utensils to obtain a status of bliya, and reguarding bishul akum I also stated in my question that since the utensils are parve having obtained no bliya, you could order a salad.

Comment: Don't cut sharp foods obtain _b'lios_ from the knife?

Answer (score 6):

There are problems with food from a vegan restaurant.

See this [Chabad site](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/547235/jewish/Are-vegan-restaurants-kosher.htm)

> A vegan restaurant would not have a hard time getting kosher
>   certification. However, as long as there is no such certification one
>   should not eat there. There are many reasons why a strictly vegan
>   establishment requires kosher certification. Here are a few of them:
>
> 1. It is possible for a minute quantity of animal products to be included in a vegan-certified food. According to the Vegan Society, an
>      outfit which licenses vegan foods, "vegan products must, as far as is
>      possible and practical, be entirely free from animal involvement."
>      Furthermore they state, "Animal products are sometimes used in
>      instances that are not immediately obvious."1
> 2. All utensils used to prepare kosher food, as well as countertops, ovens, etc., must be kosher. Meaning, if they were previously used for
>      non-kosher foods, they must be koshered before being used for kosher
>      food preparation.
> 3. Wine and grape juice are not kosher unless they are certified kosher (see Wine and Grape Products). Even if the restaurant doesn't
>      have a wine list, many dishes include wine or grape juice in their
>      ingredients.
>
> *4.   Certain foods must be cooked or baked by a Jew in order to be kosher (seeBaked and Cooked Foods).* (Doesn't apply in your case - no cooked food)

And see [this site](http://www.viciousbabushka.com/2012/03/10-foods-you-thought-were-vegankosher-but-really-arent.html) which points out:

> Unfortunately for vegans[and Kashrus observers], avoiding all animal
>   byproducts — especially bugs– in the American food system is basically
>   impossible. The Food and Drug Administration even keeps a list of how
>   many bugs and bug parts manufacturers are allowed to have in their
>   products — including many that vegans or vegetarians [and Jews] eat.
>   So how much non-vegan/[non-kosher content] might be in your food? We
>   had a look at the standards and, leaving aside how much animal feces
>   and hair is allowed, compiled 10 of the grossest.
>
> 1. Frozen or canned asparagus Producers are allowed to leave 6 or more attached asparagus beetle eggs and/or sacs on 10% of their spears and
>      either: an average of 40 thrips per 100 grams; or make sure the
>      remaining insects or insect parts have an average aggregate length of
>      7mm or longer per each 100 grams. Crunchy!
> 2. Canned lingonberries They taste so good at Ikea — but that little extra protein comes from the 3 larvae per pound allowed.
> 3. Frozen Brussels sprouts Look closely: producers can have up to 30 aphids or thrips in every 100 grams.
> 4. Canned orange juice Tangy! Producers are allowed 5 fruit fly and other fly eggs or 1 maggot in each 250 milliliters.
> 5. Canned corn Each 24 pounds of corn can have up to two corn ear worms or corn borer larvae less than 3 millimeters or longer, as long
>      as the total larvae, shed skin or fragments thereof does not exceeds
>      12 millimeters. - See more at:
>      http://www.viciousbabushka.com/2012/03/10-foods-you-thought-were-vegankosher-but-really-arent.html#sthash.YPJJLz1z.dpuf

Comment: Assuming it's a new restaurant and the utensils are new, so there's no bliya problem. And even if there are bugs they are בטול בששים.

Comment: @DavidFeigen A whole bug is a "creature" and as such cannot be botul. See http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-ABISSELBITUL.htm Berya – A complete creature (e.g. an insect), whether dead or alive, is never batel.22

Comment: The way to get around it would be to freeze the bugs thereby breaking the bugs limbs  apart and this prevents it from being a  shalem

Comment: Not so simple,ain mevatel issur lchatchila,I don't believe everyone allows freezing for that purpose

Comment: Also freezing doesn't always help

Comment: @DavidFeigen you said you were discussing raw vegetables -- a lot of them don't freeze and thaw that well. (E.g. lettuce doesn't freeze.)

Comment: The 2nd citation sounds so gross that it makes me wonder about my becoming vegan! I guess the only way is to live on a farm and be my own rav!

Comment: "3.Wine and grape juice are not kosher unless they are certified kosher " - Of particular concern are wine vinegar (which might be used in salad dressings, in particular), and, don't forget that many "naturally sweetened" fruit juices such as cranberry juice are sweetened with grape juice. Jams / preserves / jellies may have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.nishmat.net/Uploads/files/Keeping_Kosher_Eating_Out.pdf) by Nishmat's Rabbi David Sperling explains the issues of non-kosher utensils and *bishul akum* (2 and 4 from the Chabad site) more in-depth, including when they apply. He also goes into a few other issues such as *mar'it ayin*, cold and sharp foods, and additional concerns in Israel. (The article isn't specifically about vegan restaurants but is also relevant here.)