# Vinegar and Nazir

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, nozir

> Inspired by the [comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40693/if-a-restaurant-is-already-halal-how-much-more-work-is-it-for-them-to-become-ko/40700#comment108026_40700) surrounding [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40700/5323)

Since a Nazir is not allowed to drink wine, is wine vinegar also prohibited to Nezirim?

Comment: Probably "Nezirim", no?

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably....I considered using the halacha tag myself, but decided against b/c it's not really הלכה למעשה....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see Bamidbar [6:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9934#v=3)

> ג מיין ושכר יזיר, חמץ יין וחמץ שכר לא ישתה
>
> he shall abstain from wine and strong drink: he shall drink no vinegar of wine, or vinegar of strong drink (JPS 1917)

For elaboration, see Mishneh Torah Hilchos Nezirus Chapter 5.