# Can I eat any food with vinegar in it like mayonnaise, ketchup, etc if I'm a Nazirite?

Tags: noachide-laws, nozir

[Numbers 6:3-4](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0) explains that a Nazirite can't have strong drink nor vinegar of wine also can't eat anything from the vine tree or eat grapes so does that apply to any other foods with vinegar in it such as mayonnaise or ketchup?

Comment: You tagged your question with [noachide-laws](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noachide-laws). Are you asking your question about Noachides? (I could be mistaken, but I don't think Noachides can become nazirites, under Jewish Law.)

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40741/vinegar-and-nazir

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) China and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @TamirEvan you are not mistaken, non Jews cannot become Nazirites (see [Nazir 61a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.61a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Comment: A.) Only Jews can be Nazirs. B.) Standard, cheap American condiments use grain vinegar, not grape vinegar. Totally Nazir-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is relevant (because you tagged the question [noachide-laws](/questions/tagged/noachide-laws)) I would first note that non-Jews cannot become Nazirites (see [Nazir 61a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.61a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

In any case, **since wine or wine vinegar are forbidden, they cannot be eaten either when mixed into other products**. If one has mixed them (e.g., by mistake) and the taste of wine/vinegar cannot be felt, then it is permitted to eat the dish, but that is only valid after the fact due to the rule of "*ein mevatlin isur l'chatchila*".

This can be seen in the words of the Rambam (MT [Nazir 5:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/983589/jewish/Nezirut-Chapter-5.htm))

> If wine or the like were mixed together with honey and the flavor of
> wine cannot be detected, it is permitted for a nazirite [to partake of
> the mixture].

From the language ("if they were mixed") one understands that this is only permitted after the fact (*b'dieved*) but forbidden in principle (*l'chatchila*).

Comment: More importantly: standard, cheap American condiments use grain vinegar. It's far cheaper than wine vinegar. A Nazir can eat corn or wheat, or their vinegar, to his/her heart's content.

Comment: And you CAN taste vinegar in ketchup or mayo! No way no how this is "null."