# What are the potential halachic problems eating in a vegan restaurant without hashgacha?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, melacha-creative-work, restaurant

Suppose for this scenario that the restaurant is very strictly vegan (and in a region where veganism is truly understood), and there is no wine present. All dishes that the restaurant uses are strictly vegan.

I can think of a few problems, but I am hoping that someone will be able to spell out these problems in detail with sources.

An initial list of problems:

**1) Keilim** were bought used and were used in a treyf restaurant

**2) Bishul akum**

**3) Indirectly benefitting from a Yehudi's melacha on Shabbes**
 There could be a Yehudi worker who works there on Shabbes (for a kosher diner eating there during the vokh, would this be considered a violation of the issur against gaining hano'ah from a Yehudi worker's melacha on Shabbes?) or a ba'al yehudi of the restaurant who keeps the restaurant open on Shabbes (same question: would eating there during the vokh be considered a violation of the issur against benefitting from a Yehudi's melacha on Shabbes, albeit indirectly)?

Can anyone elaborate on the potential issues above-- 
if they are indeed issues or if they are not *(and why or why not, with textual support)*-- 
**and do the same for any additional potential problems that I did not list?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since one requires a trustworthy Jew to certify kashrus, one cannot trust the owners to say that it is *strictly Vegan*. Additionally, grape juice can be used in the recipes or in the juices served even if there is no wine.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a subset of (2), but yayin neshech would be a potential problem. Grape juice is used in a lot of foods, causing kashrut problems.

Comment: My answer to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36442/may-a-person-order-food-from-a-vegan-restaurant will serve here too. I believe this question is a dupe.