# Can certified vegan be assumed to be pareve?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, dairy

If a food item has a valid kosher certification, which marks it as being dairy, but also has certification from a vegan certification that it is vegan, can it be assumed to be dairy equipment?

I don't want to know if certified vegan can be assumed to be kosher, just if it can indicate lack of dairy.

Comment: This question seems to be a subset of ["Does Vegan Certification Have Any Halachic Weight?"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30363/2), in particular, "Can [these certifications] be trusted to certify, for example, that a processed product is neither dairy nor meaty ...?"

Comment: @IsaacMoses apparently so.  Do I delete my question?

Comment: no, please don't delete. It's [valuable to the Internet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) to have multiple different phrasings of the same question pointing to the same resource. This post will just get closed as a duplicate of the other.